# jQuery ready function aliases

Tags: jquery, alias, document-ready

I'm a little confused about all the different ways to create a new jQuery object.

the relevent docs seem to be:
  http://api.jquery.com/ready/
  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

From those two docs the following are all equivalent, (with the exception of aliasing or not aliasing '$'):

- $(document).ready(handler)
- $().ready(handler)
- $(handler)
- jQuery(function($) {});
- jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});

Is that correct?  Did I miss any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is another. From the docs:

> There is also
>   **$(document).bind("ready", handler)**.
>   This behaves similarly to the ready
>   method but with one exception: If the
>   ready event has already fired and you
>   try to .bind("ready") the bound
>   handler will not be executed.

The other initialiser methods will always run... so you might find yourself declaring `$(document).ready(function() { //stuff }` in a number of files for example, and the handler is always run.

I'd go with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {})` or `$(document).ready(function() {})` more often than not... I find that they're more readable.

Another approach would be to call a script just before the closing body tag and in it do something like,

```
(function($) {
    //stuff
})(jQuery);
```

if you need to avoid conflicts with other libraries using $. This is a self-executing anonymous function and it lets you use the alias in its scope without fear of conflicts from other libraries.

Comment: The `jQuery(function($){ });` lets you use `$` without conflict and on DOM ready all at the same time :)

Comment: Yes, I just find jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}) a bit more readable, though it probably doesn't make a lot of difference. The self-executing anonymous function example will offer a performance improvement since you're placing code just before the end body tag.

Answer (score 4):

These are somewhat equivalent:

- `$(document).ready(handler)` - tuns the `handler` when the DOM is loaded
- `$().ready(handler)` - runs the `handler` when the DOM is loaded (**deprecated**, don't use)
- `$(handler)` - runs the `handler` then the DOM is loaded - shortcut to `$(document).ready(handler)`
- `jQuery(function($) {})` same as #3 above, just using `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias
- `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {})` - same as the first, again using `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias

If `$` is defined as something else, e.g. Prototype, then the first 3 won't work.  The last 2 are similiar they're just accepting the first argument passed in (the `jQuery` object) and making it `$` inside, making it possible to do this even when `$` is something else:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("input").val("something");
});
```

Comment: Yep. I think the most notable being the deprecated `$().ready(handler)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are only using jQuery then $() is equivalent to jQuery(). So that covers half of them.

Then, if you use $() instead of $(document).ready, those are the same. In this case, it is just a helper function. You may want to add ready on something else for example, in which case, you would do: $(foo).load({})

Last, I don't know what you mean with $().ready because you have to pass a parameter.

Comment: Ahh no wonder I have never seen $() without parameters. It was deprecated.