# JQuery - What is the purpose of this syntax $(function () { ... });

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with SignalR, and by extension, JQuery.

Some initialisation code runs inside a function block defined with the following syntax:

```
$(function () { 

    // ... Init code here e.g. 

    var hub = $.connection.myHub;
});
```

What is the functional difference here compared with just executing scripts directly within a pair of script tags?

Comment: This should still be located inside a pair of script tags.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I know it still has to run within script tags, I mean the line of code within the function definition.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139803/jquery-ready-function-aliases

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its simply shorthand for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 6):

`$(function ()`  is equivalent to document on ready.  The function will execute everything inside the `{}` tags once the DOM has loaded.

An alternative way is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/